# Sumar meses a una fecha en php. Si la fecha inicial es 31/01/2021 y le agrego un mes obtengo como resultado 03/03/2021

Tags: php, date

Tengo una variable con la fecha 2021-01-31 y necesito sumarle un mes, pero me da como resultado 2021-03-03. Necesito que devuelva 2021-02-28.

```
// $fecha tiene 2021-01-31
$fecha = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', $fecha));
```

Que puedo hacer para que devuelva 2021-02-28?.

Comment: Prueba a ver que pasa: $fecha1="2021-01-31"; $fecha = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', $fecha1));

Comment: `+1 month` le agrega 30 o 31 días a la fecha inicial (no recuerdo exactamente cuantos) y febrero tiene 28 días. Por esa razón te devuelve el 3 de marzo.

Comment: Prueba con `'last day of +1 month'`.

Comment: @Sal funciona con "first day of +1 month",  abajo deje un ejemplo como respuesta

Comment: Creo que convendría nos des más detalles de lo que quieres lograr y qué entiendes exactamente por *sumar un mes* (sumar X días, posicionar la fecha en el 1er día del siguiente mes, etc ¿?), otro comportamiento que quizá se deba prever es el final de año, ¿qué pasa si la fecha es del mes de diciembre? Nada de eso queda claro en la pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes solucionarlo con la clase [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php), aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
$d = new DateTime( '2021-01-31' );
$d->modify( 'first day of +1 month' );
echo $d->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Aquí en la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php#107331) el compañero cristinawithout lo aclara en [su respuesta](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php#107331) ayudando a la comunidad, por eso es muy importante leer las documentaciones oficiales de [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/)

Comment: ¿Por qué si `$d` es ya un objeto `DateTime` no usas `format` para representar la fecha como se necesite? En vez de hacer esto: `$d = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d) );`, bastaría con: **`echo $d->format('Y-m-d');`**, nada más... Estás aplicando dos funciones a un objeto, ignorando totalmente la potencialidad de la POO.

Comment: Además de lo que te han mencionado, es mejor que hagas un breve resumen del contenido del enlace que proporcionás. Recordá que puede que tal contenido no esté disponible más adelante, por lo tanto, tu respuesta quedaría incompleta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Buen punto, ahí lo modifique

Comment: OK, pero no hagas esto nunca: `$d = $d->format('Y-m-d');`, `$d` es tu objeto DateTime, en algunos contextos necesitarás el objeto para otros usos, pero si lo igualas lo destruyes y ya no podrás usarlo. Simplemente haz un `echo $d->format('Y-m-d');` así, mantendrás el objeto.

Comment: no veo razón para que el objeto siga en pie, se ve mas bonito con la variable jaja

Answer (score 1):

Al decirle a la función date que sume un mes directamente, esta reconoce que debe sumar la cantidad de días del mes en corriente (sino recuerdo mal), por eso te da una fecha de marzo. Una de las soluciones más sencillas es usar la función [modify](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.modify.php) de la clase DateTime, pudiendo quedar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
//fecha inicial
$date = new DateTime('2021-01-31');

//modificas tu fecha diciendo que quieres el final de mes
$date->modify('last day of +1 month');

//respuesta esperada: string(10) "2021-02-28"
var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d'));
```

[Adjunto snippet](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/582702aeee0cb6d4ab569f8415536d504097d02f)