# Hola Buen día quisiera saber si me podrían asistir con la fecha de un proyecto que es en html y php

Tags: php, html

Tengo que duplicar un proyecto en el cual a la hora de que este se duplique la fecha de inicio y termino se sumen 1 mes mi pregunta es como podría sumar el mes al nuevo proyecto les dejo como es mi código a continuación.
Les agradecería en verdad bastante si pueden ayudarme por favor

```html
if($action == 'project_double'){
    $pname =$_POST['pname'];
    $location =$_POST['location'];
    $cost =$_POST['cost'];
    $deadline =$_POST['deadline'];
    $sdate = $_POST['sdate'];
    $tid =$_POST['tid'];
    $p_type =$_POST['p_type'];
    $file = "no_image.png";
        
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO projects (project,location,overall_cost,start_date,deadline,site_pic,tid,date_added,io,proposed_project)
        VALUES('$pname','$location','$cost','$sdate','$deadline','$file','$tid',now(),'1','$p_type')");
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    if(isset($_POST['divs'])){

    $divs= $_POST['divs'];
    $cd = count($divs);
    for($i=0; $i < $cd; $i++){
        $query2 = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO project_partition (project_id,pd_id)
        VALUES('$last_id','$divs[$i]')");
    }
    }
    if($query && $query2){
        echo '<script>$("#suc_msg2").show("slidedown");
        var delay = 1500;
                    setTimeout(function(){  window.location = "index.php?page=project_detail&id='. $last_id.'&dattyp=new&stats=1";   }, delay);
        </script>';
    }else{
        echo $query;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, podrías reemplazar la imagen por el código para poder analizarlo?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/473941/80870 Recomiendo leer la [Clase DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) especificamente [datetime::add()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.add.php)

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio, Paola, por favor, reemplaza el código que tienes en formato de imagen en tu pregunta por código legible. Para algunos usuarios simplemente les es imposible determinar qué dice en dicha imagen. Puedes leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](/help/how-to-ask) y realizar el [recorrido](/tour/)

Comment: Listo ya edite la pregunta, muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo investigar mas sobre el tema de fechas aqui [DateTime::add](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.add.php)

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como agregar mas tiempo a tu fecha, suponiendo que utilizas, timestamp en tu base de datos
`$deadline = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($sdate. ' + 1 month'));`

ya tu lo puedes ajustar a como lo manejes internamente!.

Saludos

Comment: Hola me ayudo mucho tu comentario nada mas que lo único malo es que me actualiza solo una fecha ya edite la pregunta para que puedas observar como

Comment: usa el mismo procedimiento para la otra fecha, almacenalo en una variable nueva y list